# Finding duplicate columns in a nested array

Tags: algorithm

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6
0{1,2,1,2,1,5,5}
1{5,4,5,4,5,1,1}
2{2,4,2,4,2,1,1}
3{1,2,1,2,1,1,1}
4{4,4,4,4,4,1,1}
5{2,4,2,4,2,2,2}
```

output: {{0,2,4}, {1,3}, {5,6}} (can use any data structure)

Let's say there is a nested array like above. If we wanted to find column indices that contain the same exact numbers in the same order (for example, column 0, 2, 4 with (1,5,2,1,4,2) and column 1, 3 with (2,4,4,2,4,4), and column 5, 6 with (5,1,1,1,1,2), how can we go about with this efficiently? Will it require dynamic programming?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate through the columns, keeping a hashmap of the columns that you've seen so far. Here's an implementation in python:

```
x = [[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 5, 5], 
     [5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 1, 1], 
     [2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1], 
     [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1], 
     [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1], 
     [2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2]]
seen_before = {}
for v, col in enumerate(zip(*x)):
    if tuple(col) not in seen_before:
        seen_before[tuple(col)] = [v]
    else:
        seen_before[tuple(col)].append(v)
```

This solves the problem in linear time. I hope that's good enough for you.